# How to subset a dataframe based on some conditions over the rows of dataframe that contains list in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a list of values in each rows of dataframe. I want to check some conditions and based on that condition i want to subset a dataframe. For example in belove code myDF is my dataframe. That is

```
ID  Value
A   c(1000, 2000, 3000)
B   c(2000, 500, 1000)


ID <- c("A", "B")
Value  <- list( c(1000, 2000, 3000),  c(2000, 500, 1000))
myDF <- data.frame(ID=ID, Value=cbind(Value))
vec <- c(2000,3000)
##Condition
cnd <- which(myDF$Value[[1]] %in% vec)
```

The above condition cnd will give the desired list but while putting this condition in subset function it will not get the proper index.

```
 ld <- lapply(seq(myDF$Value) , function(x) myDF[ which(myDF$Value[[x]] %in% vec),])
```

This will output as below. Because in the result the index which myDF is getting is not proper.

```
[[1]]
     ID           Value
2     B 2000, 500, 1000
NA <NA>            NULL

[[2]]
     ID           Value
2     B 2000, 500, 1000
NA <NA>            NULL
```

My desired output is below. Please help.

```
     ID  Value
A   c(2000, 3000)
B     2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
myDF$Value_filtered <- lapply(seq(myDF$Value), function(i) myDF$Value[[i]][which(myDF$Value[[i]] %in% vec)])
```

I have just changed for `1` for `i` (also in function argument) otherwise your `lapply` doesn't loop over lists in your column `$Value`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake. It works fine that is what i want.

Comment: Is there any other way than this. I can't achieve this by using subset function in r.